# Apache Arrow Datafusion RecordBatch with timestamp

Tags: rust, apache-arrow

I’m trying to clone an existing  delta table  locally using delta-rs.
I’m using `DeltaTable.get_schema().unwrap().clone();`  to get the schema  and I create a new table with

```
let mut config = DeltaOps(table).create().with_columns(schema.get_fields().clone());
```

I use datafusion a dataframe by let `df = self.ctx.sql(sql).await.unwrap();` . When I try to write the recordbatch from this dataframe by `record_batch_writer.write(batch).await?;`  I see that the recordbatchs schema has a change.  I see that the timestamp is `data_type: Timestamp(Nanosecond, None)` but the table schema has `data_type: Timestamp(Microsecond, None)`. Is there a config to fix this behaviour.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that either the delta-rs or DataFusion communities really monitor Stack Overflow. I would recommend filing a GitHub issue/discussion against one of these projects.

https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs
https://github.com/apache/arrow-datafusion